# Custom Named pipes in Linux containers - Docker for windows

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

lately I've been struggling against docker poor performance over the network and, in general, with Docker induced latency over any communication that passes through containers.

*My scenario is this:*

I have 3 containers communicating with each other, one of them (the "management" container) also communicates with the outside through port binding and exposes some services to do test stuff with the inner containers.
For the internal-external communication I've already got a solution (using the bridge network is fine even if I'm still looking for something better) but my real concern is for the intra-container communication.

***So here's the question:***
Using [this example provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) I wanted to try using named pipes in .net core inside linux docker containers under a windows host.
I'm using docker-compose so I assumed, at first, that adding the npipe as a volume would have done the trick but I'm having some issues.

With this dockerfile:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  netcorepipetest.server:
    image: netcorepipetestserver
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetCorePipeTest.Server/Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - //./pipe/PipeName://./pipe/PipeName

  netcorepipetest.client:
    image: netcorepipetestclient
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NetCorePipeTest.Client/Dockerfile
    volumes:
     - //./pipe/PipeName://./pipe/PipeName
```

And slightly modifying the source code sample like this:

**Server part**

*From:*

```
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);
```

*To*

```
  NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
                new NamedPipeServerStream(@"\\.\pipe\PipeName", PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads);
```

**Client part**

*From*

```
 NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
                    new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe",
                        PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
                        TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);
```

*To*

```
 NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient =
                new NamedPipeClientStream(@"\\.\pipe\PipeName");
```

I get this error:

```
 Cannot create container for service netcorepipetest.client: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "\\\\\\\\.\\\\pipe\\\\PipeName://./pipe/PipeName"\nis not a valid Windows path'
```

Ok, after that I've googled a bit around just to get more confused when I stumbled across a github issue (I don't really remember how to find it again fml) where someone mentioned that maybe using the long syntax in the compose-file would have done something. After updating the compose file swapping the volumes lines with:

```
volumes:
      - type: tmpfs
        #source: \\.\pipe\PipeName
        target: \\.\pipe\PipeName
```

I no longer get the error during build but in execution phase nothing that is supposed to happen happens. The server just hangs there doing nothing and the clients following up. What am I doing wrong? Is it simpler on a Linux host?

Or is it just a fantasy of mine the possibility to use custom named pipes?

P.s. (I'm using `tmpfs` as type because `bind` is just like the way it was before and it would error)

**Versions and tools:**

- *Docker version* : Docker for windows 18.03.1-ce
- *Linux Containers*
- *Host O.S*.: Windows 10 Pro (64bit)
- *.net-core version* :  2.1
- *Visual Studio 2017* as IDE

Please, if you need more details don't be afraid to ask!

Comment: On Linux I create fifos with `mkfifo` on host and share them using a mounted volume. That works quite well. I can't tell anything about .NET. Idea: Share a volume common to all containers, create a fifo with linux command `mkfifo` and try out.

Comment: Sorry but I really need to get this working in Windows before linux even if Linux will be my final deployment environment. I'm looking for a "multi O.s." solution. I'm going to try mounting a regular windows folder on all containers to see what I can get. Thanks for the interest btw :)